# Can you pre-compile regular expressions in Python, save them to a file, and then reload them from the file?

Tags: python, regex, caching

I have an application that loads a large table of regular expressions from an Excel file, compiles them, and then uses them to perform its function.  It takes about 2 minutes for Python to compile the regular expressions, which will increase as I add more expressions to the Excel file.  The Excel file does not change often, so I would like to avoid the two-minute+ startup time whenever the Excel file has not changed.

Is there a way to cache the compiled regular expressions to a file that I can load when the Excel file hasn't changed?

Comment: I would live to see an answer to your question but it doesn't seem to be coming soon, so i will write my humbe opinion. It might be better if you wrote the code and the list in c, c++ or golang, hardcode the regexes and read new regexes from a file. Furthermore, something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134589/can-i-pre-compile-a-python-script) might be of help, but i haven't seen something in the first look

Answer (score 1):

You can store the compiled regular expressions in pickle files:

```
import re
import pickle

r1 = re.compile('\d\d\d')

with open('tmp', 'wb') as fh:
    pickle.dump(r1, fh)


with open('tmp', 'rb') as fh:
    r2 = pickle.load(fh)

    print(r2.match('673'))
```

> <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='673'>

Comment: But loading those precompiled regexes is pretty much guaranteed to take more time than recompiling them.

Comment: Not if you store them in a dictionary and pickle the whole dictionary.

Comment: @John Jackson: if you find the answer useful could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: @sophros Thank you for your answer!  I'll give it a try this week and let you know how it works out!  I apologize for the late response; life has been hectic...

Comment: I finally got time to try this out today. It saved about 2 seconds out of 55.  Saving the compiled regexes appeared to be no problem, but loading them back took almost as much time as compiling them.

I ran the experiment 3 times to get a feel for the variance.  The experiment compiled 653 regexes whose total text length (uncompiled length) added up to 1042102 characters.  The regexes were contained in a dictionary, which is what I pickled and unpickled.

The average compile time was 55.4 seconds
The average pickle save time was 0.006 seconds
The average pickle load time was 53.8 seconds

Comment: @sophros I'm not sure how to "grade" your answer.  It does indeed answer the question as posed, "how to save and load precompiled regular expressions", but does not solve the problem, which is to save significant time by doing so.

Comment: @JohnJackson: Have you tried substituting `pickle` for [`dill`](https://pypi.org/project/dill/)? It is a drop-in replacement of pickle and may have a different characteristics.

Comment: Regarding grading the answer - you admitted yourself that it answers the question.